# Alguna palabra que defina algún evento alegre pero en el presente se recuerda con tristeza

Tags: gramática

¿Tenemos en español alguna palabra que exprese un estado de alegría en el pasado pero en el presente se recuerde con tristeza? Por ejemplo: un sobreviviente a un accidente de avión, se siente feliz en el momento y a corto plazo, pero en el presente se recuerda el evento con mucha tristeza

Answer (score 2):

En el ejemplo del avión, trauma.

- Triste recuerdo.
- Recuerdo amargo.
- Recuerdo no grato.
- Recuerdo poco grato.
- Recuerdo nada grato.
- Recuerdo ingrato.
- Recuerdo traumático.
- Experiencia traumática.
- Recuerdo doloroso.

---

Estado de alegría en el pasado como añoranza, nostalgia, melancolía, saudade, etc.

- Recuerdo agridulce.
- Reminiscencia agridulce
- Me dejó un sabor agridulce.

Comment: Interesante, como aficionado al Bossa Nova, conocía la palabra saudade del portugués por la canción **Chega de Saudade** y ciertamente acabo de comprobar que esta palabra esta en el diccionario de la RAE.

Answer (score 0):

Alguna palabra que exprese un estado de alegría en el pasado pero en el presente se recuerde con tristeza.

---

Desde mi punto de vista la palabra correcta, salvando algunos aspectos médicos y psicológicos que no son capaces de ponerse de acuerdo entre ellos, sería "**Síndrome**".

Imaginemos por ejemplo el *Síndrome de Stendhal*, también conocido como Síndrome de Florencia. La persona que visitan lugares conocidos y fabulosos, esta contenta, felices y alegres con su viaje, con ver tallas y obras de arte magníficas, pero los síntomas que pueden percibir y los trastornos que se deriven hace que se recuerde en la actualidad con cierta ansiedad, desasosiego ó tristeza al recordar aquello.

El *Síndrome de Estocolmo* también puede servir de ejemplo, al ocasionar trastornos psicológicos más o menos prolongados en el tiempo. Por una parte, la felicidad y alegría de una persona al sentirse liberada tras un secuestro, y por otra, la carga de haberse visto comprensivo y benevolente con sus secuestradores, produciéndose en la actualidad un rechazo, vergüenza ó simplemente tristeza al recordarlo.

Los Síndromes son un conjunto de síntomas que se presentan juntos, así algo positivo como estar en un sitio, haber sobrevivido, no ser operado, ser rehén y ser rescatado, provoca ese estado de felicidad por una parte y a la vez de tristeza cuando se piensa en el momento presente.

Existen muchas clases de Síndromes, aquí me refiero a ese conjunto de síntomas que pueden aparecer juntos, que resultan incluso contradictorios y que normalmente acaban siendo parte de otros aspectos ó dolencias psicológicas, pero ese ya es otro tema.

Sabiendo esto, en mi opinión, lo que le queda ahora es ajustar de forma más especifica los síntomas reales de las situaciones que desea enlazar, hablar de síndrome como un conjunto de síntomas provocados por ciertas experiencias ó referirse a la idea que tiene en mente simplemente como "una especie de síndrome".

Espero haya ayudado. Saludos.

Diego M.

Answer (score -1):

Perdón por entrometerme con tanta ignorancia. Pero lo único que viene a mente en primera instancia es: "Nostalgia". La evocación de un recuerdo feliz en el presente, que provoca tristeza.

Comment: Bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Recien estoy regresando de una larga ausencia así que no tomes lo que voy mencionar como si viniera de alguien familiarizado con los usos y costumbres locales. El modelo técnico de este sitio ha sido hereado de una comunidad de programadores. Por diversas circutancias esto ha influido en tener un artículo de ayuda sobre el comportamento esperado que recomienda evitar convesionalismos en la conversción escrita aunque estos comunes en otro tipo de escritos. Véase [Expected Behavior](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Por favor también lee [answer]

Comment: En concreto, evita las disculpas y cualquier otro elemento que no sea indispensable para comunicar claramente la respuesta a lo que se ha preguntado. La brevedad no debe estar por encima de ofrecer una respuesta completa, que incluya fuentes y sustente apropiadamente sus argumentos cuando esto sea necesario.